# How do I insert the IMG into the DOM from a dynamic property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following property in my view:

```
avatar: function()
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('src', 'img/people/%@'.fmt('Finck_Brian.jpg'));
    return image;
}
.property(),
```

And essentially all I'm trying to do is insert the returned element into the DOM, using the standard `{{ person.avatar }}` mark-up. However, all I get is the following:

> [object HTMLImageElement]

I'm sure there was a way in EmberJS to *unescape* the characters that are returned, because it converts the HTML to a *safe* string. Something like unescape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most simple with ember is to use the {{bindAttr}} helper.
In your template, try something like:

```html
<img {{bindAttr src="person.avatar"}}></img>
```

and your avatar property like this:

```js
avatar: function () {
  return 'img/people/%@'.fmt('Finck_Brian.jpg');
}.property()
```

Here is a small jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/dWr8T/

Now to answer to your question, you have an helper to return a safe html string. I think this should be as simple as 'your string'.htmlSafe() (In fact Ember enriches the String prototype with this function, see http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=packages_ember-handlebars_lib_string.js&src=true

Comment: Thank you again! And nice choice of picture!

Answer (score 0):

The template language you are using expects a string of HTML, not an HTML element object.

You can convert an HTML element object to a string of HTML with:

```
 var container = document.createElement('div');
 container.appendChild(desired_element);
 return container.innerHTML;
```